# Any Real-World Experience Using Software Transactional Memory?

Tags: scala, haskell, clojure, language-agnostic, stm

It seems that there has been a recent rising interest in STM (software transactional memory) frameworks and language extensions.  [Clojure](http://clojure.org) in particular has an excellent implementation which uses [MVCC (multi-version concurrency control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) rather than a rolling commit log.  GHC Haskell also has [an extremely elegant STM monad](http://research.microsoft.com/%7Esimonpj/papers/stm/beautiful.pdf) which also allows transaction composition.  Finally, so as to toot my own horn just a bit, I've recently implemented an [STM framework for Scala](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/software-transactional-memory-in-scala) which statically enforces reference restrictions.

All of these are interesting experiments, but they seem to be confined to that sphere alone (experimentation).  So my question is: have any of you seen or used STM in the real world?  If so, why?  What sort of benefits did it bring?  What about performance?  (there seems to be a great deal of conflicting information on this point)  Would you use STM again or would you prefer to use some other concurrency abstraction like actors?

Comment: If you ask this on the clojure list, you will get a lot of responses.  I believe that clojure is driven by needs Rich Hickey actually has and its STM support is there because he needs it, not as an experiment.

Comment: Oh, I'm sure I would!  But I was more interested in uses of STM outside of Clojure-land.  After all, it's hardly a new idea, there should be *someone* who finds it useful.

Comment: As a side note, it seems that there is some ongoing experimentation with STM in .NET by Microsoft - enough so to release a working implementation already: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee334183.aspx - now I doubt that this is being done just for the fun of it, and integrating with .NET definitely introduces a very pragmatic angle, and I'm inclined to treat the fact that this is even considered seriously as a single of technology maturing enough for "production".

Comment: Microsoft's experiment has ended in failure. http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/05/STM-Dropped

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I participated in the hobbyist development of the BitTorrent client in Haskell (named conjure). It uses STM quite heavily to coordinate different threads (1 per peer + 1 for storage management + 1 for overall management).

Benefits: less locks, readable code.

Speed was not an issue, at least not due to STM usage.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 28):

The article "[Software Transactional Memory: Why is it Only a Research Toy?](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cain/pubs/cascaval_cacm08.pdf)" *(Călin Caşcaval et al., Communications of the ACM, Nov. 2008)*, fails to look at the Haskell implementation, which is a really big omission.  The problem for STM, as the article points out, is that implementations must chose between either making all variable accesses transactional unless the compiler can prove them safe (which kills performance) or letting the programmer indicate which ones are to be transactional (which kills simplicity and reliability).  However the Haskell implementation uses the purity of Haskell to avoid the need to make most variable uses transactional, while the type system provides a simple model together with effective enforcement for the transactional mutation operations.  Thus a Haskell program can use STM for those variables that are truly shared between threads whilst guaranteeing that non-transactional memory use is kept safe.

Comment: The paper "Software Transactional Memory: Why is it Only a Research Toy?" is introduced by a fuming Bryan Cantrill in ACM Queue: [Concurrency's Shysters](https://queue.acm.org/blogposting.cfm?id=1127) of Nov. 2008. _"For this first article, we were lucky enough to find Calin Cascaval and colleagues, who ended up writing a must-read article on STM in November's CACM. Their conclusions are unavoidable: STM is a dog. (Or as Cascaval et al. more delicately put it: "Based on our results, we believe that the road for STM is quite challenging.")_ Muh locks!

Comment: In the end it's just like pulling the database into your programming language (or making the programming language a PL/x scripting language). This nice idea is then cruelly murdered if you proceed to work with the common database cache (i.e. use mutable state). Jonathan Allen: _The first one in which we noticed it was when one trx removes a node from a linked list, while another trx is traversing that same list. If the former thread believes it “owns” the removed element simply because it took it out of the list, someone’s going to be disappointed when its state continues to change._ 

Answer (score 28):

We use it pretty routinely for high concurrency apps at Galois (in Haskell). It works, its used widely in the Haskell world, and it doesn't deadlock (though of course you can have too much contention). Sometimes we rewrite things to use MVars, if we've got the design right -- as they're faster.

Just use it. It's no big deal. As far as I'm concerned, STM in Haskell is "solved". There's no further work to do. So we use it.

Answer (score 12):

We, [factis research GmbH](http://www.factisresearch.com), are using Haskell STM with GHC in production.  Our server receives a stream of messages about new and modified "objects" from a clincal "data server", it transforms this event stream on the fly (by generating new objects, modifying objects, aggregating things, etc) and calculates which of these new objects should be synchronized to connected iPads.  It also receives form inputs from iPads which are processed, merged with the "main stream" and also synchronized to the other iPads.  We're using STM for all channels and mutable data structures that need to be shared between threads.  Threads are very lightweight in Haskell so we can have lots of them without impacting performance (at the moment 5 per iPad connection). Building a large application is always a challenge and there were many lessons to be learned but we never had any problems with STM.  It always worked as you'd naively expect.  We had to do some serious performance tuning but STM was never a problem. (80% of the time we were trying to reduce short-lived allocations and overall memory usage.)

STM is one area where Haskell and the GHC runtime really shines.  It's not just an experiment and not for toy programs only.

We're building a different component of our clincal system in Scala and have been using Actors so far, but we're really missing STM.  If anybody has experience of what it's like to use one of the Scala STM implementations in production I'd love to hear from you. :-)

Answer (score 4):

We have implemented our entire [system](http://www.staila.com/site/en/mercury) (in-memory database and runtime) on top of our own STM implementation in C. Prior to this, we had some log and lock based mechanism to deal with concurrency, but this was a pain to maintain. We are very happy with STM since we can treat every operation the same way. Almost all locks could be removed. We use STM now for almost anything at any size, we even have a memory manager implement on top.

The performance is fine but to speed things up we now developed a custom [operating system](http://nativesystems.inf.ethz.ch/WebHomeResearchStaila) in collaboration with ETH Zurich. The system natively supports transactional memory.

But there are some challenges caused by STM as well. Especially with larger transactions and hotspots that cause unnecessary transaction conflicts. If for example two transactions put an item into a linked list, an unnecessary conflict will occur that could have been avoided using a lock free data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Akka in some PGAS systems research. [Akka](http://akka.io/) is a Scala library for developing scalable concurrent systems using Actors, STM, and built-in fault tolerance capabilities modeled after Erlang's "Let It Fail/Crash/Crater/ROFL" philosophy. Akka's STM implementation is supposedly built around a Scala port of Clojure's STM implementation. An overview of Akka's STM module can be found [here](http://doc.akka.io/stm-java).